# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::get()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpstorm, laravel-routing

I have just installed Laravel 5.1, visited the home page of my app and i get the following error:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1
>
> FatalErrorException in routes.php line 16:
>
> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::get()
>
> in routes.php line 16

This is my routes.php file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/



Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This import is wrong:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
```

You actually don't have to import any class as Laravel registers a global alias `Route`.

If you want to import the right class, that would be:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. However, little confused as I did not put that import in. As mentioned this is a fresh install of Laravel.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe your IDE did this. As you can see on [Github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/routes.php) the original file doesn't contain this line.

Comment: Yes, PHPStorm seems the likely culprit. I had it automatically detect PSR-0 namespace roots when I created the project.

Comment: Perhaps you should use command line composer dump-autoload after the laravel installation.

Comment: @MaXi32 Composer has absolutely nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: @lukasgeiter I don't have this problem using laravel 5.1 with PHPStorm 8. BTW Composer fixed most of the namespace import problem in laravel :). It works most of the time for me. My opinion :)

Comment: @MaXi32 Me neither. I suppose that PHPStorm went over all files and tried to resolve imports. And trust me, `composer dump-autoload` doesn't solve a wrong import.

Comment: @lukasgeiter And yet we still cannot answer why, PHPStorm tried to resolved the imports problem :)

Comment: @lukasgeiter PHPStorm will try to resolve the wrong imports when you did not optimize your class loader by running composer dump-autoload. Class not found exception is common in laravel. So doing composer dump-autoload 'might' solve this problem earlier before PHPStorm messed up the namespace import problem. Reference: http://developed.be/2014/08/29/composer-dump-autoload-laravel/

Comment: Installed a Laravel Snippets extension on VSCode and it imported that line automatically at some point. Just removed the line and it's working fine. Although, a bit disappointed by the extension now.

Answer (score 5):

comment this:

```
// use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
```

use this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel `VERSION = '5.2.30'` using `zendserver enterprise`

On `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\plugins\laravel\zray\ZRay.php`  from zend server, change line 193

From

```
if (get_class($route) != 'Illuminate\Routing\Route') {
```

To

```
if (get_class($route) != 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route') {
```