# Call to undefined method Route::name()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

im trying to set a name for my route

```
Route::get('test/show/{id}' , 'TestController@show');
```

accourding to documentation

> Instead of specifying the route name in the route array definition,
>   you may chain the name method onto the end of the route definition:
>
> ```
> Route::get('user/profile','UserController@showProfile')->name('profile');
> ```

so i wrote

```
Route::get('test/show/{id}' , 'TestController@show')->name('testShow');
```

but i get

```
FatalErrorException in routes.php line 28:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::name()
in routes.php line 28
at FatalErrorException->__construct() in compiled.php line 1743
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError() in compiled.php line 1738
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in compiled.php line 0
in compiled.php line 17158
at RouteServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure}() in compiled.php line 6819
at call_user_func() in compiled.php line 6819
at Router->group() in compiled.php line 17159
at RouteServiceProvider->map() in compiled.php line 925
at call_user_func_array() in compiled.php line 925
at Container->call() in compiled.php line 4858
at RouteServiceProvider->loadRoutes() in compiled.php line 4840
at RouteServiceProvider->boot() in compiled.php line 17153
at RouteServiceProvider->boot() in compiled.php line 925
at call_user_func_array() in compiled.php line 925
at Container->call() in compiled.php line 1518
at Application->bootProvider() in compiled.php line 1510
at Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}() in compiled.php line 1511
at array_walk() in compiled.php line 1511
at Application->boot() in compiled.php line 1785
at BootProviders->bootstrap() in compiled.php line 1311
at Application->bootstrapWith() in compiled.php line 1928
at Kernel->bootstrap() in compiled.php line 1890
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter() in compiled.php line 1880
at Kernel->handle() in index.php line 53
in index.php line 21
at {main}() in index.php line 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::get()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285647/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-routing-routeget)

Comment: can you paste your alias for route class in config/app.php file in aliases section ?

Comment: @Roboticsexpert  im using a clean installation of laravel for test so most options are on default value here it is `'Route'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',`

Comment: what is version of your laravel ? i edit my post ... plz see my edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This import is wrong:

> use Illuminate\Routing\Route;

You actually don't have to import any class as Laravel registers a global alias Route.

If you want to import the right class, that would be:

> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

on top of route.php file

EDIT:
this problem 
Works fine for me... Are you sure you have at least Laravel 5.1 version? This feature wasn't available in 5.0

If not :
You need to run

> `composer update`

in your terminal
 to get the latest Laravel 5.1.* version.

Comment: nope , i'm not importing anything in the routes.php (btw i tried it but didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

For me `->name()` only works like this:

```
Route::get('test/show/{id}' , ['uses' => 'TestController@show'])->name('testShow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this route :

```
Route::get( 'test/show/{id}', [ 'as' => 'testShow', 'uses' => 'TestController@show' ] );
```

What version laravel you used? I think it's version affect to the function.