# NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 269:

Tags: laravel

Check this codes:

setting.blade.php

```
 <form action="{{ action('HomeController@getBackgroundTheme')}}" method="post">
                                <span class="setting-name">THEME</span>
                                <!-- <form method="POST" action="/posts"> -->
                                {{ csrf_field() }}  
                                <span class="setting-value center">

                                <select name="menu">
                                    <option value="Landscape">Landscape</option>
                                    <option value="Lifestyle">Lifestyle</option>
                                    <option value="Music">Music</option>
                                    <option value="Office">Office</option>
                                    <option value="Hobby">Hobby</option>
                                    <option value="Politic">Politic</option>
                                    <option value="Building">Building</option>
                                </select>
                                <!-- <div style="width: 150px; height: 30px;"><input type="image" src="http://localhost/framework_freshway/public_html/images/submit.png" value="SUBMIT" width="10"> -->
                                <a href="{{ Url('home/users') }}">List User</a>

                                @if(isset($member))
                                @foreach($member as $m)

                                <tr>
                                    <td><img width="200px" height="200px" src="{{url('/')}}/uploads/theme/{{$m->pic_name}}"/></td>
                                </tr>

                                @endforeach
                                @endif
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
                                </span>                                         
                                <br><br><br>    

                                </form>
```

route.php

```
Route::post('/home/theme', 'HomeController@getBackgroundTheme');
```

HomeController.php

```
 public function getBackgroundTheme()
 {

$model = theme_background::all();
return view('soulfy.setting', ['member'=>$model]);
 }
```

I wonder why after pressing submit. The user being carried to: http://localhost/soulfy_repo/public_html/home/background-theme

NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 269: Controller method not found.

Answer (score 0):

Change your action of form on submit like this:

from

```
action="{{ action('HomeController@getBackgroundTheme')}}"
```

to

```
action="{{URL::to('/home/theme')}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a name to your route and call it by her name:

```
Route::post('/home/theme', 'HomeController@getBackgroundTheme')->name('getBackgroudTheme');
```

Then in your form:

```
action="{{ route('getBackgroudTheme')}}"
```

Comment: That routes create this error:  FatalThrowableError in routes.php line 57: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::name()

Comment: You imported the incorrect library, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111281/call-to-undefined-method-routename you wouldnt need to import any class

Comment: Still do not understand how to fix it?

Comment: Just remove  `use Illuminate\Routing\Route` from the top of your routes file

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a working solution, then replace first line of your form with this

`<form action="{{ URL::to('/home/theme') }}" method="post">`

and this will work absolutely fine.